# IP Classes, What is and what isn't possible?

Tags: ip, subnet

So, I've been looking on different websites, and using different subnet calculators, where in some cases it's possible and others it isn't possible.

Are these IPs possible?

Class A:  11.66.12.49/6 (Less than 8 network bits)

Class B:  133.22.15.1/10 (Less than 16 net bits)

Class C: 201.2.115.25/18 (Less than 24 net bits)

Sources:

http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=201.2.115.25&mask1=18&mask2=

http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=C

So basically, can you have a class C IP address with 5 netbits? or a class B for that matter?

Comment: @glglgl still a useful skill, what terrible CS program were you in?

Comment: useful? it is obsolete, outdated and hasn't any relevance any longer except for computer archaeologists.

Comment: To make myself clear: it MAY be useful to know about them, but only passively (know what it is about) and not actively (use it). And not at all *only* knowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Basically, the classes are the IP address ranges:

```
  - Class A: 0.0.0.0 - 126.255.255.255
  - Class B: 128.0.0.0 - 191.255.255.255
  - Class C: 192.0.0.0 - 223.255.255.255
  - Class E: ...
  - Class F: ...
```

With that said, if your in a classful network, you have to use the default subnet masks: /8 - /16 - /24.

On the other hand, if your in a classless network, you may use any subnet mask, no matter the value of the first octet.

Hope this helps!

Sources:

- [Classless Networks] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing
- [Classful Networks] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network

Answer (score 2):

There haven't been classes A, B and C since CIDR was introduced in 1993.

So all of your given networks are possible.